# Can a GitLab CE export from one namespace be imported into to gitlab.com in a different namespace?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8

As per the title, I am attempting to import a project previously exported from GitLab CE 8.10.4 as a new project on www.gitlab.com.

I am following the instructions here: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/settings/import_export.html

To illustrate my use-case:

1. Export project from GitLab CE: `mynamespace/myproject`
2. Import the exported project to www.gitlab.com: `yournamespace/myproject`

At present the result I am getting is an empty project at `yournamespace/myproject` following the import completing with no obvious reason for failure.

[image: Empty project following import]

If I click the **Import respository** button I get the following message, not sure if it's relevant / related to my problem?

[image: Validation failed: User already exists in source]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some experimentation the answer this question is yes.

The problem described was actually occurring due to a bug with GitLab. Clicking the `Create empty bare repository` button actually displays the project just imported.

As of this writing (17/8/16) the GitLab Import feature has been disabled on www.gitlab.com until the feature is fixed.